# How to find the breakpoint numbers in pdb (ipdb)?

Tags: python, breakpoints, ipdb

Trying to find how to execute ipdb (or pdb) commands such as `disable`.

Calling the `h` command on `disable` says

> disable bpnumber [bpnumber ...]
>   Disables the breakpoints given as a space separated list of
>   bp numbers.

So how whould I get those bp numbers? was looking through the list of commands and couldn't get any to display the bp numbers

**[EDIT]**
The `break`, `b` and `info breakpoints` commands don't do anything, although in my module i clearly have 1 breakpoint set like this `import pdb; pdb.set_trace( )` - same for `ipdb`. Moreover `info` is not defined.

The output of `help` in `pdb`:

> Documented commands (type help ):
>   ======================================== EOF    bt         cont      enable  jump  pp       run      unt    a      c          continue 
>   exit    l     q        s        until  alias  cl         d         h
>   list  quit     step     up     args   clear      debug     help    n
>   r        tbreak   w      b      commands   disable   ignore  next 
>   restart  u        whatis break  condition  down      j       p
>   return   unalias  where
>
> Miscellaneous help topics:
>   ========================== exec  pdb
>
> Undocumented commands:
>   ====================== retval  rv

And for `ipdb`:

> Documented commands (type help ):
>   ======================================== EOF    bt         cont      enable  jump  pdef    psource  run      unt    a      c
>   continue  exit    l     pdoc    q        s        until  alias  cl
>   d         h       list  pfile   quit     step     up     args   clear 
>   debug     help    n     pinfo   r        tbreak   w      b
>   commands   disable   ignore  next  pinfo2  restart  u        whatis
>   break  condition  down      j       p     pp      return   unalias 
>   where
>
> Miscellaneous help topics:
>   ========================== exec  pdb
>
> Undocumented commands:
>   ====================== retval  rv

I have saved my module as pb3.py and am executing it within the command line like this

> python -m pb3
>   The execution does indeed stop at the breakpoint, but within di pdb (ipdb) console, the commands indicated don't display anything - or display a NameError

If more info is needed, i will provide it.

Comment: I'm trying disable breakpoints but no info is printed.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `break` command. Don't add any line numbers and it will list all instead of adding them.

Comment: What is your python and ipdb version?

Comment: `ipdb` interfaces with `ipython` and tries to have the same interface as `pdb` which comes with python 2 & 3. Here are the documentation for it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break and https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break

I'm using Python3.6 with `ipdb==0.11`

Comment: `python 3.7.8,` am I using IPDB?